# How To Get The URL After Redirecting from Current Page To Another Using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, backend, puppeteer

I'm *Aadarshvelu*! Recently Started Testing My WebApp Code Using **Jest** With **Puppeteer**. So I Have Page Which All Credentials Have Been Filled With **Puppeteer**.But When SummitButton('signBtn') Clicked **POST** process Starts

**Is There Any Test That Process POST Request?**..

Or

**How Do I Know Test Has Been Completely Finished?**

Or

**How to  Get The Redirect Page URL While Test Running?**

This Is My Code!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const timeOut = 100 * 1000;

test("Full E2E Test!" , async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo:30,
        args: ['--window-size=1920,1080']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://mypass-webapp.herokuapp.com/signUp');

    await page.click('input#email');
    await page.type('input#email', 'Automation@puppeteer.com');
    await page.click('input#username');
    await page.type('input#username' , "puppeteer");
    await page.click('input#password');
    await page.type('input#password' , "puppeteer");
    await page.click('#signBtn').then(await console.log(page.url()));

    // Here I Need a Test That Checks The Current Page!

    await browser.close();

} , timeOut);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Is There Any Test That Process POST Request?..

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.click('input[type="submit"]'), // After clicking the submit
  page.waitForNavigation() // This will set the promise to wait for navigation events
// Then the page will be send POST and navigate to target page
]);
// The promise resolved
```

---

2. How Do I Know Test Has Been Completely Finished?

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.click('a.my-link'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
  page.waitForNavigation('networkidle2') // The promise resolves after navigation has finished after no more than 2 request left
]);
// The promise resolved
```

---

3. How to Get The Redirect Page URL While Test Running?

For example, if the website http://example.com has a single redirect to https://example.com, then the chain will contain one request:

```
const response = await page.goto('http://example.com');
const chain = response.request().redirectChain();
console.log(chain.length); // Return 1
console.log(chain[0].url()); // Return string 'http://example.com'
```

If the website https://google.com has no redirects, then the chain will be empty:

```
const response = await page.goto('https://google.com');
const chain = response.request().redirectChain();
console.log(chain.length); // Return 0
```

---

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer Dude!, It Really Works!!,                                 I Hope You're Doing Well :)

Comment: Hi @EdiImanto, I really like your answer. can you please tell me how can we load all the resources like css, js, and image from our proxy server using Puppteer?

Comment: This did not work for me. It showed the original url and a wrong redirect code 307 rather than what really happened which was 302. I found that a simple `page.url()` after the `await page.goto(..)` gave me the final redirected url.

Answer (score 0):

`await page.click('#signBtn')`

After this simply make another page

---

`const [, page2] = await browser.pages();`

---

And here is your redirect Page Url

```
  const redirectPageUrl  = page2.url();
  console.log(redirectPageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `await page.goto(..)`, simply do a `page.url()`. It will give you the final url after any redirects have taken place.

Here is my reference: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2215#issuecomment-455695684

It worked for me.

The `HTTPRequest.redirectChain()` way (which was one of the answer reply of this question) of trying to get the final redirected url did not work. Weirdly, it showed `307` with the same original http url, when infact a `302` was happening and it redirected to the https url